# Finding point of intersection

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

q 23

my solution[image]

I attempted like above.Then to check i plotted graph 
on desmos. so it showed me three roots.One before zero also. So i tried using first dervivative to get monotonocity of the function, yet am not able to reach a proper solution.

Comment: question is itself saying to equate to 2x^2-2

Comment: sir, passage 7, question 23.

Comment: As you have worked it, the vertex of the parabola is at $(-\frac 12, \frac 32)$  But as you have drawn it, you have up it at $(0,2)$  The parabola should be cutting more steeply at $x = 0$ dropping below the exponential on the left of 0, before rising again.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the continuous function

$$ U(x)=f(x)-h(x)-2x^2+2=2^x+3^x-2(x^2+x+1) $$

We know that as $x$ increases the exponential portion will eventually overpower the polynomial portion and the function will be positive from that point on. So begin by plotting a few points.

1. $U(0)=0$ so we have at least one solution
2. $U(1)=-1$ so there is at least one positive solution since it must eventually be positive
3. $U(3)=9$ confirmed. So because the graph is continuous there is at least one zero between $1$ and $3$.

Taking the first derivative gives

$$ U^\prime(x)=2^x\ln 2+3^x\ln 3-4x-2 $$

Then $U^\prime(0)=\ln 6-2<0$. So the function is decreasing at $0$ which means it is positive in value just to the left of $0$. So for some small number $a<0$ we have $U(a)>0$. But $U(-1)=-\frac{7}{6}<0$. So there is a change of sign on the interval $(-1,a)$ from negative to positive. Thus there is at least one zero between $-1$ and $a$. So there are at least three zeros.

**ADDENDUM:** See the comment of @String below.

Comment: U(x)=f(x)-h(x)+....

Comment: @AvinashN Thanks!

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: Very nice! Just add that $U'(x)=0$ implies $2^x\ln x+3^x\ln 3=4x+2$ where the LHS is a convex function and the RHS is a straight line, so this has at most two solutions. Hence three zeros of the original function is also an upper bound.

Comment: @String Excellent comment!

Answer (score 0):

Number of roots=3.
[image]

[image]

I am using**Geogebra** for drawing this curve.